# Why do my variables attach to each other instead of adding together?

Tags: javascript

The perimeter for my code always comes back like 2020 4040 and so on and I cannot seem to figure out why when the variables are both numbers. I know it is a pretty simple fix but I cannot figure it out. I tried parseInt but that did not work either. Can anyone help explain to me what I need to add or change to get my perimeter to come up say 40 using say 10 and 10 for the width and height.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <p>Click the button to calculate the area and perimeter of a rectangle.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it out!</button>    

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            var width = prompt("Please enter a width", " ");
            var height = prompt("Please enter a height", " ");
            var area = width * height;
            var perimeter = (width + height) * 2;

            if (width != null && height != null) {
                alert("The area is " + area + " and the perimeter is " + perimeter + ".");
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `prompt` always returns a string, and `+` is used to concatenate strings ... Convert the values to numbers before doing the maths.

Comment: prompt() returns a `String`. The + operator for strings is equivalent to string concatenation. You need to turn your width and height into `Number`.

Comment: I would do something like **this**: http://jsbin.com/xuzijopade/1/edit?js,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add parseInt around your prompt will parse the prompt string to an int. The math will then work correctly. (using + with strings will concatenate the strings and not add them as you desire).

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
    <p>Click the button to calculate the area and perimeter of a rectangle.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it out!</button>    

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
            // Make sure your prompt is parses as an int.
            var width = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a width", " "));
            var height = parseInt(prompt("Please enter a height", " "));
            var area = width * height;
            var perimeter = (width + height) * 2;

            if (width != null && height != null) {
                alert("The area is " + area + " and the perimeter is " + perimeter + ".");
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`prompt` always returns a string. You have to convert it to a number before doing a `+`. Otherwise, it just concatenates.

You can do something like

```
var width = parseFloat(prompt("Please enter a width", " "));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because

```
var height = prompt("Please enter a height", " ");
```

gets a string value for 20, instead of Number value for 20, as I assume you wanted.

This might be what you are looking for: [How do I convert a string into an integer in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1133770/how-do-i-convert-a-string-into-an-integer-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

if you are positive it always come back as a number.  Force it to become a number by multiple it by 1.  see https://jsfiddle.net/ktaacx92/

```
var width = prompt("Please enter a width", " ") * 1;
var height = prompt("Please enter a height", " ") * 1;
```

but i recommend a quick form.

Answer (score 0):

Put the plus sign (`+`) in front of `prompt()` calls.  This will cast the input as a number.  (code pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jrryBP).

JS:

```
function myFunction() {
  var width = +prompt("Please enter a width", " ");
  var height = +prompt("Please enter a height", " ");
  var area = width * height;
  var perimeter = (width + height) * 2;
  if (width != null && height != null) {
    alert("The area is " + area + " and the perimeter is " + perimeter + ".");
  }
}
```

Comment: will not work if you input a char :)

Comment: The OP's request focuses on conversion of valid numeric strings into numbers.  The post does not deal with the validation of the said data.